# Fazer update no oracle via método c#

Tags: c#, oracle

criei um método que faz update no oracle.
Porém, está absurdamente lento quando ele o faz.
Quando faço outras operações como "INSERT e SELECT" nessa mesma tabela,
o tempo de resposta é bem rápido.
Poderiam me ajudar, por favor?

Segue abaixo o código:

```
    public void UpdateUsuario(string usuario, string novosetor)
    {

        string sql = @"UPDATE cda_f_usuasetor USUASETOR SET CDA_N_SETOR = '" + novosetor + "' WHERE CDA_X_USUARIO = '" + usuario + "'";

        OpenConnection();
        using (Cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, Con))
        {
            Cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataReader dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Close();
        }
        CloseConnection();



    }
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Esta mesmo operação executa de forma rápida, quando executada diretamente no seu banco de dados?

Comment: Veja se há um índice no campo "CDA_X_USUARIO", além disso não passe valores diretamente para seu comando pois você está sujeito ao SQL Injection.

Comment: Bruno, sim. Quando executo direto no Oracle . Executa de maneira rápida

Comment: Leonardo, não contém índice. Como vc recomendaria que fizesse?

Comment: Assim: "CREATE INDEX IX_CDA_X_USUARIO ON cda_f_usuasetor (CDA_X_USUARIO)". Também, em seu código como você está executando uma query onde não há retorno, mude para "Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery" e remova a variavel OracleDataReader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie um índice na sua coluna na qual você está fazendo o where (CDA_X_USUARIO), nisso já irá melhorar a performance do seu update.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_CDA_X_USUARIO
    ON cda_f_usuasetor (CDA_X_USUARIO)
```

Seu código tem um grave problema de segurança, pois da maneira que você está montando a sua query (concatenando a instrução com as variaveis) ele está sujeito ao SQL Injection.

Para evitar isso, é recomendado que você não monte os parâmetros diretamente, e sim passe através do método "AddWithValue". Assim, seu código ficará desta maneira:

```
public void UpdateUsuario(string usuario, string novosetor)
{
    string sql = "UPDATE cda_f_usuasetor USUASETOR SET CDA_N_SETOR = :P_NOVO_SETOR WHERE CDA_X_USUARIO = :P_USUARIO";

    OpenConnection();
    using (Cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, Con))
    {
        Cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P_NOVO_SETOR", novosetor);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P_USUARIO", usuario);
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    }
    CloseConnection();
}
```

Por último, você não precisa usar o `OracleDataReader` neste caso, pois você não está utilizando nenhum retorno. Perceba que fiz a substituição do método do reader para `Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`, que retorna apenas o número de linhas afetadas.

Comment: O problema era que estava com o Oracle aberto com a tabela consultada enquanto fazia pela aplicação, mas agradeço a recomendação e vi realmente que não estava fazendo uma boa prática. Farei dessa maneira, sempre.